# Posterior Distribution using a Normal Likelihood and Laplace Prior

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, mathematical-statistics, conjugate-prior

I have the working out below but is this correct. I just want the posterior distribution of when mu=0 given x.

[image]

What I have tried is setting mu=0 after rewriting the first pdf with the summation symbol. Then this allows me to bring the absolute value in the other exponential over. But I am unsure as to whether the jump from the second last proportional to the last proportional to is correct (where I remove the xbar^2/sigma^2)

Ultimately I want a Laplace Posterior and going to desmos gives me the following curve (which is what I want) when taking the second line of working out (where the summation is removed) I just need to prove this algebraically.

[image]

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: I have now added this to the question! Plus I've completely derived this for a different purpose but just wanted help on the algebra of it!

Comment: Computing the density at a specific value of the random variable ($\mu$) does not make much sense. Using the proportionality sign for a specific value of the random variable ($\mu$)  even less, as $\pi(\mu=0|x)\propto 1$ as well.

Comment: So what steps do you recommend that I change? Because I am kind of stuck at this point

Comment: A Laplace prior is not conjugate to a Normal likelihood, so you should not expect a Laplace posterior distribution